# Using Storyboard ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, push, segue

What would be main difference between using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier and performSegueWithIdentifier ?

I think that performSegue.. is used for normal pushing of viewControllers as instantiateViewController is used for some kind of modal showing of viewController and then dismissing it when used.

Since there are also modal and custom push in storyboard I'm not sure about my theory so if anyone could explain when to use which one ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that `performSegueWithIdentifier` is used to transition to a specific view controller *that is connected by a segue* in interface builder (Transition1 in my screenshot).

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` can be used to instantiate *any view controller on a storyboard*, regardless if it's connected by a segue or not (Transition2 in my screenshot).

Push, modal, or any other custom transition could be used for either scenario.

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` can also be used to instantiate view controllers from separate storyboard files. A segue has to be within the same storyboard file.

[image]

The segue identifier used in `performSegueWithIdentifier` needs to be set in interface builder.

[image]

The view controller identifier used in `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is the Storyboard ID field in interface builder.

[image]

Comment: I get the idea but you can connect any controller to any other with segue or not connect anything and use instantiate method. Are there any rules when to use which ?

Comment: You can instantiate view controllers from separate storyboard files using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. A segue has to be within the same storyboard file.